# how to save state of a View and restore it when the user comes back in?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm creating an Android application, where I have an interaction with two different views, so the user can switch between them by a Button Click. Note that I'm using setContentView method. So how can I save the state of each view (containing EditText , Buttons which can be enabled/disabled) and restore it  when the user leaves the view and come back to it?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout1);
}


@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle State) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(State);
    State.putCharSequence("key" , txt.getText());
}
```

(txt) is an EditText .

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle State) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(State);
    txt.setText(State.getCharSequence("key"));
}

public void method1(View view) {
    setContentView(R.layout.id1);
}

public void method2 (View v){
   setContentView(R.layout.id2); 
}
```

I want to restore the state of layout1 when the user goes back to it.

Comment: Leaves the view to where? To another activity? Exits the activity? Most probably you need to use ROOM

Comment: leaves the to another one by a button click , in just one activity i have two different layout files in one activity .

Comment: @GayaTouak see my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading about the Activity lifecycle, specifically the part about saving and restoring UI state, which can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#saras). Basically, you need to save your UI state in `onSaveInstanceState()`.

EDIT: What happens right now is that the `EditText` value is not saved since you called `super.onSaveInstanceState(state)` first. Save the `EditText` value first to the `Bundle`, then call `super.onSaveInstanceState(state)`:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle State) {
    State.putCharSequence("key" , txt.getText());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(State);
}
```

Then on your `onRestoreINstanceState`, you don't have to call `super`, you can just grab the saved value and set it immediately to your `EditText`.

Comment: thantks , but here i have two layout files in juste on activity . i override the onSavedInstanceState method , onRestoreInstanceState but this stops the app .

Comment: @GayaTouak can you post your code and the error found in the logcat when the app stops?

Comment: i'v tried this , but it doesn't work . thank you for your help ! i'm sorry if i disturbed you .